# ¿Cuándo se comenzó a usar la palabra "circo" en español con su significado actual?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, historia, sustantivos

He visto este fin de semana *[The greatest showman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1485796/?ref_=nv_sr_1)* en cines, en la cual dan a entender que el protagonista, [P. T. Barnum](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._T._Barnum), es el responsable de que hoy día la palabra "circo" tenga el siguiente significado:

> Edificio o recinto cubierto por una carpa, con gradería para los espectadores, que tiene en medio una o varias pistas donde actúan malabaristas, payasos, equilibristas, animales amaestrados, etc.

Es cierto que la palabra *circo* ha sufrido una considerable evolución a lo largo del tiempo. Desde Covarrubias, que solo hace referencia al circo romano, y el Diccionario de Autoridades, que considera que es una grada redonda en la que unos a otros no se tapan la vista, no fue hasta 1869 que se incluyó una tímida definición como "lugar destinado para los ejercicios gimnásticos y ecuestres". En 1899 ya pasó a ser:

> Edificio público, con gradería para los espectadores y en medio un espacio circular, donde se ejecutan ejercicios ecuestres y gimnásticos.

Esta definición cuadra bastante con lo que se ve en la película, dado que al principio el "circo" de Barnum estaba dentro de un edificio y se llamaba "museo", cambiando de denominación a "circo" tras una crítica destructiva aparecida en un periódico.

En todo caso, y dejando de lado las definiciones del diccionario, ¿cuándo se comenzó a usar en español la palabra "circo" con su acepción (casi) actual de lugar destinado a ejercicios gimnásticos y ecuestres?

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el [REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Banco de datos (CORDE) [en línea]. Corpus diacrónico del español](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=25&ordenar1=1&ordenar2=0&FID=200418%5C005%5CC001O20042018052403351.1204.1200&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20circo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1775-1820%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0). http://www.rae.es [18/IV/2018] encontré que c. 1818 (fecha que confirma [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Joaqu%C3%ADn_Fern%C3%A1ndez_de_Lizardi#Obras)), *La educación de las mugeres o La Quijotita y su prima* (sic) [dice](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=WjUqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP250&lpg=PP250&dq=%22hacer%20maromas%20en%20el%20circo%22&source=bl&ots=Yn6GUewZZs&sig=EKBlI9jTtw7KvWlKLE1zWLXuFhQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNrIfOrMXaAhXLk1kKHYoHBBIQ6AEINjAG#v=onepage&q=%22hacer%20maromas%20en%20el%20circo%22&f=false):

> (...) Y desde ahora prometo que voy a empeñarme con papá para que Laislón me instruya en el arte de la equitación, por si algún día me viere en necesidad de hacer maromas en el circo (...)

Por lo visto ya en esa época se iba al circo a hacer maromas en artes ecuestres, 
y el texto es de un escritor mexicano (José Joaquín Fernández de Lizardi) la palabra tendría algunos lustros previos (teniendo en cuenta que hace 2 siglos la comunicación de un lado al otro del océano tardaba un poco más y el tiempo que transcurre para que una palabra se escriba en cuanto se ha popularizado oralmente...) especulando, a fines del siglo XVIII el circo dejaba de ser 'edificación' para ser 'espectáculo'.

Al hacer una revisión extra, Gaspar de Jovellanos lo menciona en sus [Memorias sobre la diversión pública](http://bdh.bne.es/bnesearch/CompleteSearch.do;jsessionid=71BB54CD68D2FE74724B5D13EE6C4B80?text=&field1val=%22Jovellanos%2C%20Gaspar%20Melchor%20de%22&showYearItems=&field1Op=AND&numfields=1&exact=on&textH=&advanced=true&field1=autor&completeText=&pageSize=1&pageSizeAbrv=30&pageNumber=16) (1790) veamos como interpreta al circo en su libro (2 veces mencionado):

> No merece por cierto tan amarga censura otra diversión coetánea de los juegos del circo y de la liza, y harto más racional que entrambas, esto es, los convites, saraos y fiestas palaciegas(...)
>
> (...)De el primer pueblo de la antigüedad,  del que le diera leyes al mundo, decía Juvenal que se contentaba en su tiempo con pan y juegos del circo. El nuestro pide menos(...)

El segundo es el claro ejemplo del circo romano. El primero ya da a entender que es un circo con el que se entretienen en su época. ¿Qué hacían en ese circo? no queda muy claro. Cabe aclarar que ese párrafo inicia un capítulo que sigue a una censura al toreo y a las justas, pero no he leído todo el libro

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el  *circus maximus* de los romanos es el orígen del circo actual. 
Los romanos tenian espectáculos con artistas y animales entre otros eventos en el *circus*.  La palabra *circus* quiere decir círculo.

La evolución de *circus* a circo es conocida.  La evolución a un espectáculo bajo una carpa es bastante natural.